# Given a set of objects, how to calculate how many fit in a given volume?

Tags: algorithm

This is more an algorithm question than programming, but it's implemented in programming so I'm asking it here.

I have a set of given objects with different known dimensions and need to figure out the max of objects that can be put inside another volume of known dimensions. What algorithms exist to explore this problem other than a combinatorial brute-force approach?

Also, if I assume they are not arranged, how many will fit?

Another way to look at it:

1. What's the max of a set of LEGO blocks I can assemble to put
   inside a box and how do I calculate it?
2. What's the max of a set of LEGO blocks I can drop inside a box without arranging them 
   and how do I calculate it?

Comment: What do you mean by "not arranged"? If you literally drop bricks one at a time into a box, and count how many times you can do that before one pokes out above the top, then it's random (or rather, it's sensitive to the details of how each one is dropped). You won't get the same answer every time if you try it in real life.

Comment: You're right, Steve. What I'm expecting in this case is that if you repeat the experiment as you describe, you'll get an average of how many have fit and knowing the optimal fit you'd be able to calculate the average-bloat-by-random or how much they grow by not being arranged.

Comment: @Steve no but there would presumably be a lower bound? which is a sort of 'inverse' knapsack problem, the knapsack problem being the upper bound

Comment: @jk.: yes, there must be a lower bound since there's a set of non-negative integers `x` such that some arrangement of `x` blocks resulting from a series of drops, fails to fit. Any set of integers bounded below has a least element. Of course the lower bound would look like the worst Tetris player ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic CS problem - read the wiki entry on [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).