# Determining package dimensions for UPS Shipping Rate API

Tags: php, algorithm, e-commerce, ups

I am coding a custom commerce CMS in PHP.
I have been integrating the UPS XML API for getting Shipping Rates and currently have it working. I am using Mark Sandborn's PHP class http://code.google.com/p/ups-php/

The API requires input of the final package's *Length*, *Width*, *Height* and *Weight*. My product database has this info for each respective product, so no problem when someone purchases just one item. Slightly different story when **multiple products** are added to the cart... The final *Package Weight* is still easy since it I can just grab the sum of all *product weights*.

However what are best practices for estimating the final package's Length, Width and Height to pass to UPS when multiple products are in the cart?

**Amendment**
It seems to me that any developer working with the UPS API in a store environment must deal with this same issue. More so than a solution to the knapsack problem I'm hoping I am misunderstanding something about how the API works and that there's actually a simple way to deal with this or even a way to hand off this to UPS to calculate.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648859/given-a-set-of-objects-how-to-calculate-how-many-fit-in-a-given-volume Do you have specific box sizes that you're trying to fit everything into? That would certainly affect the outcome of this algorithm.

Comment: Hmm since this will be a CMS used for many different stores, I do not have info on specific box sizes. I believe other CMSs like X-Cart, Magento, Zen Cart, etc also use the UPS API to calculate shipping, so I hoped there would be a common approach to handling this issue.

Comment: I've found this--not sure if it works exactly for what you need: https://github.com/yetzt/boxing

Comment: Thank you beanland. Although it isn't exactly what I need it was helpful to look how they handled some of the calculations.

Answer (score 3):

You are basically trying to find the same software that business use when designing 2D shapes. They get first a flat material surface, and then, with the objects they want to obtain, optimize the arrangement so no material is wasted.

This is not an easy task; I would say it's a huge task even considering all your objects are perfect boxes.

Also I think you could actually write a whole book about this as some people has done. If you are still willing to do it automatically instead of trying manually, read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem) Wikipedia article.

And [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?635047-Packing-Math-Problem-%28PHP-Experts-Only%29) there is an old but still helpful forum conversation about it for PHP. They also suggest the try-and-see that is optimal, which I think it's your best option.